# Permission Denied on "docker compose exec --user alice app /bin/bash"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my Dockerfile, I create a user, "alice" (generic name that isn't industry-specific) with a home directory. Alice has `/home/.bashrc` and `root` has `/root/.bashrc` (which all users can read - `chmod a+r /root/bashrc`).

I can run `docker compose exec app /bin/bash` and access the app container's command line as the root user. I can then `su alice` and have full access to the container as Alice.

However, if I run `docker compose exec --user alice app /bin/bash`, I get "bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied" followed by the "alice@sha:working/directory" cli prompt. `ls ~/` gives the error: "ls: cannot open directory '/root/': Permission denied".

My docker-compose.yml file (abridged):

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - HOST_GID=${HOST_GID}
        - HOST_UID=${HOST_UID}
    volumes:
      ${full_source_path}:/var/www/html
      ...
    env_file: .env
```

My Dockerfile (abridged):

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM php:7.1-apache

# Set up Apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# UID & GID are passed in to use the same UID/GID as the host user's user account
ARG HOST_UID
ARG HOST_GID
RUN echo "Creating alice" && \
    groupadd \
        --force \
        --gid ${HOST_GID} \
        alice && \
    sync && \
    useradd \
        --no-log-init \
        --uid ${HOST_UID} \
        --gid ${HOST_GID} \
        --create-home \
        --shell /bin/bash \
        alice \
        && \
    sync && \
    echo "DONE"

# copy externally created files, including .bashrc, into /home/alice/
...

RUN chmod a+r /root/.bashrc
RUN chmod a+r /home/alice/.bashrc

RUN echo "Finalizing" && \
    chown -R alice:alice /home/alice/ && \
    echo "DONE"

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Persist cached writes
RUN sync

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

My `entrypoint.sh` file:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

echo "Starting Apache"
exec apache2-foreground

echo "Container Ready"
sleep infinity
```

My host:

- MacOS 12.4
- Docker Desktop 4.10.1

Comment: It looks like your Dockerfile wants to run a PHP application.  How is the `alice` user related to that PHP application; why does it need shell dotfiles; and why does your container run `sleep infinity` as its main process?

Comment: This is a dev environment. The `alice` user is like a `www-data` user and a whole bunch of processes are handled by it as well as access to network shares. This is a huge app that has parts that are nearly 20 years old. `sleep infinity` is a cheat to keep the main process running indefinitely.